# Python,MySQL - unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

I Was Making A Bank Management System Using Python And The Program Shows Error,
Can Someone Tell Me What I Need to Change.

Code

```
    def DepAmo():
        amount=input("Enter The Amount You Want To Deposit")
        ac = input("Enter Your Account Number: ")
        x=0
        a='select balance from amount where AccNo=%s'
        data=(ac,)
        x=Mydb.cursor()
        x.execute(a,data)
        result=x.fetchone()
        t = result[0] + amount
        sql=('update amount set balance where AccNo=%s')
        d=(t,ac)
        x.execute(sql,d)
        Mydb.commit()
        Main()
```

Error I Get

```
in DepAmo
t = result[0] + amount
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string, so `amount` is a string. `result[0]` is an `int`. You need to convert `amount` to an integer before you can add them.

Comment: Why are you using two queries? `UPDATE amount SET balance = balance + %s WHERE AccNo = %s`

Comment: You're also missing `set balance = %s` in the `sql`.